# Save a Layout that's bigger than device screen to bitmap

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, drawingcache

I need to save the contents of a layout onto a bitmap for later usage, however, the issue I'm facing is that said layout is way bigger than the device screen.

Browsing through stackoverflow questions I've come to the following code:

```
private void viewToBitmap(View view) {

    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + name + ".jpg";
    File imageFile = new File(mPath);

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    int quality = 100;
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
}
```

It works as intended for layouts that are the same size or smaller than the device screen, but when I try to convert the layout I need, I get the following error:

> LinearLayout not displayed because it is too large to fit into a software layer (or drawing cache), needs 9334080 bytes, only 3686400 available

Is this even possible at all or I'll have to get creative and do something like use multiple layouts that fit into the screen and save into multiple bitmaps separately?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Bitmap.  Create a canvas that draws to it.  Call onDraw of your layout, passing in that Canvas.  It will draw the layout to the bitmap.  Of course, I'm assuming you have enough memory to allocate that bitmap.  If not, you're out of luck.